# Inverting certain words in a phrase

Tags: javascript

im trying to invert every second word of a sentence. i.e 2nd, 4th,6th,8th,.. words. This is what i got so far and i just cant manage to set the counter right. my words are all being inverted instead of the ones i wanted. im still in the basics of javascript and this problem will be much easier with the use of functions and arrays but i cannot use those.

```
var str=prompt("Enter")
var length=str.length;    
var sentence="";    
var word = "";    
var counter = 1;

for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {   
    if (counter = 2){    
      if (str.charAt(i) != ' '){    
        word = str.charAt(i) + word;
        counter = 1
      }else {
        sentence += word +" ";
        word = "";
        counter=2
      }
   }
}

sentence += word;    
alert("the result is: "+sentence);
```

Comment: Sure, let me play with yours real quickly. Can you use `substr` at least?

Comment: yes you can. I never thought about using that. i remember seeing that with charAt.

Comment: Sure, one moment please.

Comment: Added additional answer with nothing but `+` `-` variables, some `if else` statements, and basic `string concatenation`. Hopefully that'll work for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Something like this ought to do the trick:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/QP4fL/5/

**It's a big long winded, but it does exactly what you're looking for without some of the operators you said you couldn't use in the simplest `syntax` possible:**

```
var str="Test to make sure that this is working.";
var length=str.length;    
var sentence="";    
var word = "";   
var counter = 0;

for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {
    if(str[i]===" " && counter === 1){
        sentence += word+" ";
        counter = 0; word = "";
    } else if(str[i]===" " && counter === 0){
        sentence += word+" ";
        counter++; word = "";
    } else if(length-1 === i){
        word += str[i];
        sentence += word;
    } else if(counter === 1) {
        word = str[i] + word;
    } else {
        word += str[i];
    }
}

alert("the result is: "+sentence);
```

#### Explanation via comments:

```
/* Define our base variables. We need a few things. A string to test,
the length of the string, what our sentence will end up being, a temp
word variable, and a counter to determine odds/etc. */

var str=prompt("Enter: ");
var length=str.length;    
var sentence="";    
var word = "";   
var counter = 0;

/* Typical for loop for every character in the string you provided. */
for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {

// Now we need to know a few things, as I'll discuss as we get to them.

/* First check. If we encounter a " " AND the counter is at 1 (meaning
we are at the second find of a " ", we want to add the word to our sentence
plus an additional space to make up for the lack of catching the " ". 
Furthermore, we need to reset our counter and our word variables. */
if(str[i]===" " && counter === 1){
    sentence += word+" ";
    counter = 0; word = "";

/* Second check. If we encounter a " " but the counter is still at 0,
we want to increment counter and add the word normally. Also, reset
the word. */

} else if(str[i]===" " && counter === 0){
    sentence += word+" ";
    counter++; word = "";

 /* Third check. If we encounter the end of our string, we may as well
 just print our word as is. */
} else if(length-1 === i){
    word += str[i];
    sentence += word;

 /* Fourth check. If we encounter a series of letters where the counter
 is at 1, we can reverse the string by adding `str[i]` BEFORE the current
 word string. This will ensure the NEW characters precede the EXISTING ones. */
} else if(counter === 1) {
    word = str[i] + word;

// And, if none of the above is true, just add the letter to our word string.
} else {
    word += str[i];
}
}

alert("the result is: "+sentence);
```

Comment: Explanation available if desired.

Comment: this is what i was aiming for from the start. but then was trying out stuff and got lost. thanks

Comment: Yup, added explanation for ya. Thanks for the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
var str = prompt("Enter"),
    words = str.split(' ');

for ( var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if ( i % 2 != 0 )
        words[i] = words[i].split('').reverse().join('');
    }

alert("the result is: " + words.join(' '));
```

First, i made an array of words using `words = str.split(' ')`.
I loop over every word and reverse letters  of the word only for this condition `i % 2 != 0`.
Fianally, i put every words of the array back to a sentence using `words.join(' ')`

Comment: Thank you. We still have not learned how to use split yet. Therefore i cannot use it. But ill keep it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Well, I decided to just tackle it a different approach (explanation below).**

http://jsfiddle.net/43DXM/2/

```
var str = prompt("Enter");
var sentence = [];
var split = str.split(' ');
function reverse(s){
    return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}
for(var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
    if(i%2===0){
        sentence.push(split[i]);
    } else {
        sentence.push(reverse(split[i]));
    }
}
var final = sentence.join(" ");
alert("the result is: "+final);
```

---

**Explanation:**

- Set up your `str` as you did previously.
- Let's use an array to gather words instead of the mentioned method.
  It makes manipulation a little easier.
- Use the `split` method to split the suggested `string` up by the
  `spaces` it finds.
- Write a `quickie` `reverse function` to handle each call easily.
- Run a `for loop` to find the odd numbers, and `push` those items to
  our `array`, or for `even` items, it will `push` the `reversed value`
  to the `array sentence`.
- `join` all items in your `sentence` array with a `space` inbetween.
- **Voila**

http://jsfiddle.net/43DXM/2/

#### Edit: It appears that morgul's answer shorted the same principle a bit and chained the commands instead of laying it out long hand. Well done mate.